# selecting data where column is array

Tags: mysql

i have two tables

tb1

```
tb1_id          -       store_ids      -           date
  1             -        1,2,3,4       -        2023-01-01
  2             -            3,4       -        2023-06-01
```

tb2

```
tb2_id          -       name      -              date
 1              -       gold      -           2023-01-01
 2              -       mond      -           2023-01-01
 3              -       burgar    -           2023-01-01
 4              -       glass     -           2023-01-01
 5              -       blackD    -           2023-01-01
```

what i have tried is

```
sql
SELECT * 
FROM `tb2`
JOIN `tb1`
WHERE `tb2_id` IN (`store_ids`)
```

and i get error

> 'Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 1,2,3,4'

Comment: You shouldn't store foreign keys as csv. That is very bad db design

Comment: read about `find_in_set`

Comment: find_in_set shows empty results @Jens

Comment: can you share your db strucure? because your query runs perfectly @diyeco5337

Comment: @diyeco5337 mybe you use it in the wrong direction

Comment: For want of a many-to-many intersection table...

Comment: My bad ....find_in_set is working just fine @Jens

Comment: already did @Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [find_in_set](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp)

```
select * from tb1 join tb2 on find_in_set(tb2_id ,tbl1_id)
```

But as I mentioned in my earlier comment, it is better to redesign your table

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/4bSArccw)

Answer (score 0):

You could try below query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tb2`
JOIN `tb1`
WHERE `store_ids` REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',`tb2_id`,'[[:>:]]') -- MySQL 5.6
-- For MySQL 8.0, using WHERE `store_id` REGEXP CONCAT('\\b',`tb2_id`,'\\b')
```

But it's better to not store foreign keys as list of ids separated by comma.

Comment: I think it would not work if you have id's > 10

Comment: @Jens You're correct. I've updated my answer.